# On what programming language game engine "Frostbit 3" is written?

Tags: c++, game-engine

On what programming language game engine "Frostbite 3" is written?

Comment: Let's say it's C++. What would that change for you? What is your actual question?

Comment: On what programming language game engine “Frostbit 3” is written? It's title and my question -_-

Comment: @KirillZhukov: Repeating yourself _again_ isn't going to address Shahbaz's comment. His point is this: why do you care what it's written in? What are you trying to do?

Comment: What is wrong with my question? I just asked about language? I don't know about this and didn't find it in the Internet so I decided to ask here. I am just interesting.

Comment: This question is not off-topic whatsoever. Close-addicts, just go away.

Comment: (Though it has been suggested to me, and I agree, that this may be better suited to http://gamedev.stackexchange.com).

Comment: This is off-topic on gamedev since it's more about industry trivia and not about an actual problem faced by a user.

Comment: @JoshPetrie: The "actual problem" is that he doesn't yet hold this knowledge. Why is everybody so afraid of accruing knowledge _for interest's sake_? It always has to be about profit nowadays, huh? Perhaps open up your mind to the amazing world around you and consider whether you may be a happier person if you chose to learn as much about it as you can.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit You are welcome to voice your opinion on the [meta question](http://meta.gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/626/is-how-was-entire-game-x-made-off-topic) in which the community chose the site policy. I am simply relaying the information: migrating this question to GDSE would only result in closure.

Comment: @JoshPetrie: Except that is not at all the same question.

Comment: I apologize for off-top. I am new here. Sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Frostbite is proprietary and this information doesn't appear to be officially released.

However, based on the target platforms and the use of DirectX, I'd say that C++ is a very good bet, yes.

Another clue is [the requirement of C or C++ knowledge for a role developing games with Frostbite](https://career4.successfactors.com/career?career_ns=job_listing&company=EA&career_job_req_id=27079&selected_lang=en_US) (though this doesn't directly demonstrate that Frostbite itself is written in these languages).

Comment: So a Lead Online Engineer that should have distributed systems experience is working on a 3D engine?;)

Comment: @ThomasJungblut: What's wrong with that? Frostbite is a game engine not a "3D engine" and, as such, I'm sure networking is a part of its capabilities.

Comment: In particular, a Lead **Online** Engineer better be familiar with distributed systems.